# Convert CURL API command to Python API using requests and json

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests

I am connecting through an API to receive data. From the website API documentation, the instructions use either two CURL methods to connect the API; however, I need to connect using python.

1st Method
Curl Example

```
curl -d '' -X POST 'https://api.bcda.cms.gov/auth/token' \
    -H "accept: application/json" \
    -H "authorization: Basic <Client_Secret>"
```

My Python Conversion:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.bcda.cms.gov/auth/token'
       headers = {"accept": "application/json", "authorization": 'Basic',
            '<API_Key>': '<API_Secret>'}

r = requests.post(url = url, data ={}, headers = headers)
   print(r)
```

2nd Method Curl

```
curl -d '' -X POST 'https://api.bcda.cms.gov/auth/token' \
    --user <Client_Key>:<Client_Secret> \
    -H "accept: application/json"
```

My 2nd Python conversion code:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.bcda.cms.gov/auth/token'

user = {"<Client_Key>":"<Client_Secret>", "accept": "application/json"}

r = requests.post(url = url, headers = user)

print(r)
```

I am receiving a 403 connection error, meaning "response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it."

Comment: This may be of help: https://curlconverter.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `auth` parameter and not `headers` to convert `--user` option

```
headers = {'accept': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, auth=(client_key, client_secret))
```

Comment: That worked! After you receive the "Client Token", How do you add this into the scripting?

Comment: I suppose you have to use `headers={'Authorization': client_token}` at each request. The client token is probably returned in `r`

Comment: Does the client_token go in the header or in the auth?

Comment: In the header for sure.

Comment: So kinda like this?
headers = {'accept':'application/fhir+json', 
                        'Prefer': 'respond-async', 
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer {client_token}}

Comment: Yes, I think it should be the right way. Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: https://bcda.cms.gov/guide.html#try-the-api

This is the CURL 

```Curl -X GET 'https://sandbox.bcda.cms.gov/api/v1/Patient/$export' \
-H "accept: application/fhir+json" \
-H "Prefer: respond-async" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}"
``` 
and this is the python conversion

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/fhir+json',
    'Prefer': 'respond-async',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {access_token}',
}

response = requests.get('https://sandbox.bcda.cms.gov/api/v1/Patient/$export', headers=headers)
```
I keep getting the 401 error

Comment: Don't forget the `f` before `f'Bearer {access_token}'` (the f-strings) else `access_token` will not be evaluated.

Comment: ```
headers = {'accept':'application/fhir+json', 
                        'Prefer': 'respond-async', 
                        'Authorization': f'Bearer {"Token"}',
          }
response = requests.get('https://sandbox.bcda.cms.gov/api/v1/Patient/$export', headers = headers)

print(response)
```
Response 401. Do you know what could be doing this

Comment: Remove double quotes `f'Bearer {Token}'` or https://stackoverflow.com/a/45868297/15239951

Comment: So the actual token is not in ''. when I do it without, its a parsing error

Comment: How do you retrieve your bearer token from `r` response?

Comment: This is not the actual token. This is just what it looks like when I run the following code.
```
r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, auth=(client_key, client_secret))
print(r)
r.json()

```
Output:
<Response [200]>
{'access_token': 'herwufhrfuhewrufherwuhweKEFHUHFW.KFOKFWEROKEWP',
 'token_type': 'bearer'}

Comment: Use `access_token = r.json()['access_token']` to set the variable `access_token` then in other requests: `requests.get(..., headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}', ...})`